# d3 svg zoom does not work when neighbouring element exists

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, overlay

I am using a div containing other divs as an overlay on top of (or underneath) an svg. This will allow me to put rich html based functionality on top of the svg, such as scrolling tables, not unlike google maps overlays. I'm just getting the concept working at the moment, and the key difficulty is getting the divs to stay with the svg points they are tied to.

The zoom code in the sample below does not work unless I remove or hide the overlay div.

I've tried:
- moving the div out of "outerdiv" - doesn't work because div receives no data (the enter function seems to stop working)
- setting z index on the svg and the overlay div
- moving the svg before or after the overlay div

Whatever I do the zoom event doesn't fire, but if you hide the div with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` in CSS, it works fine

```js
var
  outerwidth = 1000,
  outerheight = 500,
  width = outerwidth,
  height = outerheight,
  rectwidth = 200,
  rectheight = 50;
var div = d3.select(".outerdiv");
var overlay = div.select(".overlay");
var svg = div.select("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
  .attr("class", "svgnetwork");

var g = svg.append("g");

overlay.style("width", outerwidth + "px").style("height", outerheight + "px");

var data = [
  ["Test1", 15],
  ["Test2", 25],
  ["Test3", 10],
  ["Test4", 20]
];

var nodes = overlay.selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div").attr("class", "node")
  .style("top", function(d, i) {
    return i * 100 + "px";
  })
  .style("left", function(d, i) {
    return 0 + "px";
  })
  .style("width", rectwidth + "px")
  .style("height", rectheight + "px")

// inner text content of node
nodes
  .append("div").text(function(d, i) {
    return "Content : " + d[0] + " " + d[1];
  });

// rects which should appear in the same places as divs
g.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "noderect")
  .attr("width", rectwidth)
  .attr("height", rectheight)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 100;
  })
  .attr("x", 0);

// set svg viewbox
svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);

// uncomment the next line and zoom on svg works
// overlay.node().style.display = "none";
svg.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 2])
  .on("zoom", function() { // zoom fires on pan and zoom
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    return false;
  })
);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #ffffee;
  z-index: 2;
}

.outerdiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.node {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.noderect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

The end goal is to get the divs in the overlay to move with the svg content as we zoom and pan, but obviously the first step is to get it zooming at all.

thanks

**EDIT: THE FINAL SOLUTION INCLUDING OVERLAY DIVS ZOOMING AND PANNING**

https://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/z6ef2uwg/

Thought this might be quite a common requirement and therefore useful to someone :)

Comment: I think that the problem is that your overlay is on top of your svg and the pointer events are captured by the div element and not the svg. Try adding  `pointer-events: none;` for the `.overlay` class. Also zoom should be called on a d3 selected element: `d3.select('svg').call(d3.zoom()`

Comment: Thanks, the accepted answer fixed it. I was surprised that the svg cannot get itself on top of the div with either ordering or z-index, but I suppose the pointer events solution is architecturally more attractive anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add `pointer-events:none;` to overlay div

```
.overlay {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

then underlying `svg` will receive mouse events

```js
var
  outerwidth = 1000,
  outerheight = 500,
  width = outerwidth,
  height = outerheight,
  rectwidth = 200,
  rectheight = 50;
var div = d3.select(".outerdiv");
var overlay = div.select(".overlay");
var svg = div.select("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
  .attr("class", "svgnetwork");

var g = svg.append("g");

overlay.style("width", outerwidth + "px").style("height", outerheight + "px");

var data = [
  ["Test1", 15],
  ["Test2", 25],
  ["Test3", 10],
  ["Test4", 20]
];

var nodes = overlay.selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div").attr("class", "node")
  .style("top", function(d, i) {
    return i * 100 + "px";
  })
  .style("left", function(d, i) {
    return 0 + "px";
  })
  .style("width", rectwidth + "px")
  .style("height", rectheight + "px")

// inner text content of node
nodes
  .append("div").text(function(d, i) {
    return "Content : " + d[0] + " " + d[1];
  });

// rects which should appear in the same places as divs
g.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "noderect")
  .attr("width", rectwidth)
  .attr("height", rectheight)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 100;
  })
  .attr("x", 0);

// set svg viewbox
svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);

// uncomment the next line and zoom on svg works
// overlay.node().style.display = "none";
svg.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 2])
  .on("zoom", function() { // zoom fires on pan and zoom
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    overlay.raise()
    return false;
  })
);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #ffffee;
  z-index: 2;
}

.outerdiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.node {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.noderect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

but you need to apply transforms to overlay too